# f(x).subs() substitution in sympy

Tags: python, function, sympy, substitution

I'm trying to find a way to substitute a variable by another one in a function. (not in an expression)
in the example below, in the function v(t), I want to substitute the variable t0 by the value 0.

the issue :
v(t) = v(t).subs({t0:0}) causes an error
v(t).subs({t0:0}) doesn't make the substitution

so how could I make this substitution.
it works fine with expressions, but is it possible to do the same in a function, and if yes, how?

Thanks for your help, guys.

```
# importation of modules required
import sympy as sy
from sympy import symbols,  Function

# defintion of the symbols required and the function  
Fnet, v0, t0, t, m = symbols('F_net v_0 t_0 t m')
def v(t):
    return Fnet*t/m - Fnet*t0/m + v0
display ("v(t)", v(t))

# trying to substitute t0 by 0 in the function v(t)
v(t).subs({t0:0})
display ("v(t)", v(t))

# note : v(t) = v(t).subs({t0:0}) causes an error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing is mainly due to the misunderstanding between symbolic functions and Python functions.

In your code, `v(t)` is defined as a Python function which returns a SymPy expression. When you try `v(t).subs({t0:0})`, it correctly substitutes `t0` with `0` in the expression `v(t)`. However, it does not change the Python function `v(t)` itself, which will continue to return the original expression every time it's called.

How you can implement above steps:

```py
import sympy as sy
from sympy import symbols,  Function
from IPython.display import display

Fnet, v0, t0, t, m = symbols('F_net v_0 t_0 t m')

def v(t):
    return Fnet*t/m - Fnet*t0/m + v0

# Display original v(t)
display ("v(t) before substitution", v(t))

# Make a substitution in the expression returned by v(t)
new_expression = v(t).subs({t0:0})

# Redefine v(t) to use the new expression
def v(t):
    return new_expression

# Display new v(t)
display ("v(t) after substitution", v(t))
```

After running the above code, the new `v(t)` will always return the expression with `t0` substituted by `0`.

Comment: perfect, thank you, that's exactly what I needed. so, what I wanted to do (only replace t0 by 0 is done by the code I had written, but to display it, I just needed to define a new expression new_expression = v(t).subs({t0:0}), and display that new expression. I'll get that logic into my brain. thanks a bunch. 

Comment: Rather than overwrite your original function, just capture the substituted expression with `vt0 = v(t).subs(t0,0); display(vt0)`